# Android BottomSheet handle recreation on activity recreation

Tags: android, bottom-sheet

I'm extending `BottomSheetDialogFragment` to create my `bottomSheet`.

I then have a delegator (receives `supportFragmentManager` as a constructor parameter) responsible for showing the bottom sheet and setting a callback.

```
val dialog = MyBottomSheetDialog.newInstance()

        dialog
            .setListener(this)
            .show(supportFragmentManager, TAG)
```

The callback is stored as a var in `MyBottomSheetDialog`.

While I'm showing the bottom sheet, if my activity is recreated, (on low-end devices is as simple as turning off or on the screen), my bottom sheet is also recreated but since it's a new instance, I lose the listener.

Since, when I create the dialog I don't have the activity but rather a delegate, how should I handle the new instance created and the callback being lost?

Can we prevent the bottom sheet from being recreated?

Comment: can you full show the code?

Comment: This is precisely why a listener isn't listed as one of the ways of [communicating with fragments](https://developer.android.com/guide/fragments/communicate)

Comment: @ianhanniballake Sorry for the late response. Missed the comment. Will change the implementation.
Another question. How can I disable the bottom sheet from being recreated when the activity is recreated? In some situations, if the activity is recreated I don't what the bottom sheet to show again.

Comment: There are hundreds of reasons why your activity would be recreated, including things completely out of the user's control (taking a phone call, etc.). You should never lose the user's state.